# Mongoose nested schema array - Object has no method 'id'

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to define a folder schema in Mongoose. For each folder, I'd like to store a reference to the parent folder, as well as an array of child subfolders (to make traversal in either direction easy):

```
var folderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Folder' },
    subfolders: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Folder' }],
});
```

When creating a folder, I want to be able to only specify the parent folder, and then have a [pre-save hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) take care of adding the subfolder to the parent folder's `subfolders` array. This part works fine:

```
folderSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var self = this;

    // If creating a subfolder, then add the subfolder to
    // the parent folder's "subfolders" array

    if (this.parent) {
        Folder.findById(this.parent, function (err, parent) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (parent) {
                parent.subfolders.push(self);
                return parent.save(next);
            }
            return next();
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Also, when deleting a subfolder, I would like to use a pre-remove hook to automatically remove the subfolder from the parent folder's `subfolders` array. Unfortunately, I can't get this part to work:

```
folderSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    var self = this;

    // If deleting a subfolder, then remove it from the parent
    // folder's "subfolders" array
    //
    // (Note: it would also be a good idea to recursively remove
    // all subfolders here, but I'm not attempting this yet.)

    if (this.parent) {
        Folder.findById(this.parent, function (err, parent) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (parent) {
                parent.subfolders.id(self._id).remove();    // TypeError: Object 53a64349741d1ae82274c9a2 has no method 'id'
                return parent.save(next);
            }
            return next();
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

The line that's erroring out is this one:

```
parent.subfolders.id(self._id).remove();
```

It results in this error:

```
TypeError: Object 53a64349741d1ae82274c9a2 has no method 'id'
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\index.js:53:35)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:97:20)
    at C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1393:13
    at model.Document.init (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:250:11)
    at completeOne (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1391:10)
    at Object.cb (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1150:11)
    at Object._onImmediate (C:\Users\serg\temp\mongoose\folders\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:137:16)
```

What I was trying to do is use the [`MongooseDocumentArray#id`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray-id) method to remove the sub document, as shown in the example on the [Sub Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) page of Mongoose's documentation. However, it looks like that method is not available, and I'm not sure why that is. Did I define the schema incorrectly? Is the `id` method not available from within middleware? Or am I simply not using it correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference here is that you're using an embedded reference to the object in your array, rather than a direct sub-document.  In the mongoose example of sub-document, it shows:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema]
});
```

So in this example, each "child" is actually stored directly within the "parent" (so the child lives within the parent collection).  In your scenario, you have a reference to your `subfolders` ID rather than the direct storing of the object:

```
subfolders: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Folder' }],
```

So when you perform your query, the result in `subfolders` is actually an array of IDs, one of which is `53a64349741d1ae82274c9a2`.  This has no method `id` which is causing your problem.  However, you could use [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to populate the objects for those IDs.  But even doing that wouldn't give you the `DocumentArray` function you need, since mongoose treats these as simply an `Array`, rather than a `DocumentArray` (which would have the `id` function you are looking for).  [You can see the logic which it uses to determine how to cast these objects here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/42e8e58f06c6b194e91c208596b0a2c5e7ed6618/lib/schema.js#L332-L351).  In the end, you'll see that when you load these objects mongoose casts them as an `Array` type:

```
return new Types.Array(path, cast || Types.Mixed, obj);
```

So if you want this `id` function you can change your schema, or simply do what it does in place.  [The logic isn't that much](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/923ca233f12428498041b2c6356eb67f68d87f9c/lib/types/documentarray.js#L106-L118), so you might consider just searching the array for the one that matches that ID manually.

Comment: Thank you for that wonderfully clear explanation - I understand now why it wasn't working before, and it led me to what I think is a good solution: I simply replaced the line that errored out with `parent.subfolders.pull(self._id);` (It uses [`MongooseArray#pull`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-pull)) So far, it appears to do what I need and is just as simple. Let me know if there might be a better way. (I'm not sure I can change my schema to use sub docs directly given that the schema references itself.)

Comment: Thanks! Based on this, I'm using `_.some(array, function(_id) {return _id.equals(id);})` to tell whether an embedded reference array contains a given `id`.